# Java Map.put() throwing null pointer

Tags: java, dictionary, nullpointerexception

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE. It looks like it is, on the surface, but the solution for the other problems does not apply.

When I run the following method under Java 1.7, I get a null pointer exception at

`normalOutCurrVals.put(new Double(x), new Byte(i));`

I have read the documentation and the answers here for closely related problems, but so far I and my team are stumped. Is there something obvious that we are missing?

We simply wish to put in the mappings from double values (that appear on our programs UI) over to their byte counterparts for storage in a simulated device's memory.

Here are the importants declarations:

```
public final Map<Double, Byte>   normalOutCurrVals =   mapNormalOutCurrVals();
public final Map<Double, Byte>   magnetOutCurrVals = mapMagnetOutCurrVals();
public final Map<Integer, Byte>  freqVals          = mapFreqVals();
public final Map<String, Byte>   onTimeVals        = mapOnTimeVals();
public final Map<String, Short>  offTimeVals       = mapOffTimeVals();
public final Map<String , Short> pulseWidthVals    = mapPulseWidthVals();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private Map<Double, Byte> mapNormalOutCurrVals(){

    Map<Double, Byte> map = new HashMap<Double, Byte>();
    double x = 0.000;
    byte i = 0;

    //first set of normal output currents
    while (x <= 2.000){
        normalOutCurrVals.put(new Double(x), new Byte(i));
        x += 0.125;
        i++;
    }

    while (x <= 4.000){
        normalOutCurrVals.put(new Double(x), new Byte(i));
        x += 0.250;
        i++;
    }

    while (x <= 8.000){
        normalOutCurrVals.put(new Double(x), new Byte(i));
        x += 0.500;
        i++;
    }

    return map;
}
```

Comment: What is `normalOutCurrVals`? Is it `null`?

Comment: Why do you do `new Double(x)`? Autoboxing should take care of that.

Comment: Why are you creating a `map` (and returning it empty), but calling put on `normalOutCurrVals`?

Comment: So `normalOutCurrVals` uses itself during its initialization. You seem to have a typo. Use the new `map` instead.

Comment: The solution does apply. It will always apply. There is only ever one reason for `NullPointerException`. Debug your code and find out what is `null`. (Hint: it's `normalOutCurrVals`.)

Comment: @ tobias It doesn't auto-box. Eclipse insists that I explicitly convert to class Double

Comment: @JonahHavel Then it looks you are using Java 1.4 source compatibility.

Comment: have you tried i = (byte) (i + 1); instead of i++; I dont know if you can do it with i++

Comment: Two problems, you are returning an empty map, and in the private method you are accessing the public variable which hasn't been initialised.

Comment: yes, I am supposed to be using map instead. Thanks Pillar.

Comment: What a dork. I actually have several versions of this method, for different types of values. This one is the only one with the typo. Yet, I still didn't see it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want to fill your map!

```
private Map<Double, Byte> mapNormalOutCurrVals(){

Map map = new HashMap();
double x = 0.000;
byte i = 0;

//first set of normal output currents
while (x <= 2.000){
    map.put(new Double(x), new Byte(i));
    x += 0.125;
    i++;
}

while (x <= 4.000){
    map.put(new Double(x), new Byte(i));
    x += 0.250;
    i++;
}

while (x <= 8.000){
    map.put(new Double(x), new Byte(i));
    x += 0.500;
    i++;
}

return map;
}
```